# R: Vector Group by Defined group

Tags: r

I have a vector `c("A","B","C",......)` and a list `list(c("A"),c("B","C"))`
I want to get a vector `c(1,2,2....)`
Is there any function in some basic packages?

Comment: Do you have the length of the vector always same as the `unlist(lst`)`?

Comment: According to the comments under @akrun answer (whish sounds correct to me) you should really [edit] your question to clarify what you want exactly from this vector and list to get this output.

Comment: Is this a fair way to reword your question?  "I have a vector `v1 <- c("A","B","C",......)` and a list `lst <- list(c("A"),c("B","C"))` I want to get a vector `value_in_lst_element <- c(1,2,2....)` where the integer is the `lst` element number where the `v1` element is found."

Answer (score 1):

we can use `merge`

```
 merge(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))), data.frame(values=v1))$ind
```

Comment: @Benjamin `v1` is the vector

Comment: why not just `stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)))$ind` ?

Comment: @CathG Initially, I thought that way, but the `vector` part is confusing, so used `merge`

Comment: probably safer indeed, as we don't really know all constraints from the Q

Comment: Or maybe just `rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst))`? Not sure what the vector supposed to do here neither.

Comment: I do think OP wish to get in which list index the value from vector is, so the merge sounds the way to go.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one.